# Bluetooth not seeing mouse (Fedora)

Tags: linux, fedora, bluetooth

I have a Lenovo S10 'netbook' that I've installed Fedora 17 ("LXDE spin") on. So far pretty much everything works great, except, the on-board Bluetooth. **lsusb** shows the controller present (0a5c:2101 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller), **hcitool dev** shows hci0 present, but when I put my mouse ("Lenovo Bluetooth Laser Mouse," which works perfectly paired with a MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, Mac mini, and Lenovo SL500 (with a USB dongle; running Windows 7)) into pairing mode and run **hcitool scan** (reports "Scanning ..." and, without further information or error message, returns to the shell prompt), **blueman-manager**, or **bluetooth-wizard** (from the gnome-bluetooth package) and try to detect the mouse, I get nothing... Frustrating!

Thanks anyone who can point me in the right direction!